# Creating a Fixed Output Jitter/Elastic Buffer

Tags: c, audio, buffer

I am trying to create a buffer for using HDRadio ([nrsc5](https://github.com/theori-io/nrsc5)) in c.

HDRadio bursts packets based on bandwidth.
It can be within this range:
(N-D) ≤ n ≤ (N+D).

- N = 32 (Average)
- D = latency (Normally: 2)

This causes underruns without proper buffering.

The idea is to create a simple buffer *that* outputs data at a **fixed rate**. It should end up outputting N packets consistently to "create a fixed delay process". [Reference: chapter 4.3 Audio Transport (elastic buffer)](https://www.nrscstandards.org/standards-and-guidelines/documents/standards/nrsc-5-d/reference-docs/1017s.pdf)

I've tried looking up existing code such as [JitterBuffer.cpp](https://github.com/yingwang/adaptive-jitter-buffer/blob/master/Source/JitterBuffer.cpp) which uses min, avg, and max values. It has issues leading to underruns due to it accelerating and not creating a fixed-delayed process.

- How do I properly implement this?
- What calculations can I use to handle packet bursts within the specified min, avg, max range? Is some standard?

All I can find are white papers that provide descriptions without providing actual *implementation*

#### Test Data / Reproduction

I created sample data to be able to reproduce this problem. [link to download](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/ajwkmh6zglopijb5cz95k/sample.data?rlkey=gnxsxq47ctqetf92y4t2yllgz&dl=1)

Quick code to read the sample data:

```c
#include <pthread_time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int big_int_endium(const uint8_t* bytes)
{
    return (bytes[0] << 24) + (bytes[1] << 16) + (bytes[2] << 8) + bytes[3];
}

int read_big_int_endium(uint8_t* bytes, FILE* f)
{
    if(fread(bytes, 1, 4, f) < 0)
        return 0;
    return big_int_endium(bytes);
}

int main()
{
    uint8_t bytes[4];

    FILE* f = fopen("sample.data", "rb");

    while (fread(bytes, 1, 4, f) > 0) {
        const int wait_time_nanoseconds = big_int_endium(bytes);
        const int packets_length = read_big_int_endium(bytes, f);

        // simulate broadcast delay of packets
        struct timespec delay = { wait_time_nanoseconds / 1000000000, wait_time_nanoseconds % 1000000000 };
        nanosleep(&delay, &delay);

        printf("packets_length: %d\n", packets_length);

        for(int i = 0; i < packets_length; i++)
        {
            const int program = read_big_int_endium(bytes, f);
            const int segment_numbers = read_big_int_endium(bytes, f);
            const int length_bytes = read_big_int_endium(bytes, f);

            uint8_t* buffer = malloc(length_bytes);
            fread(buffer, 1, length_bytes, f);

            printf("%d seq: %d length: %d\n", program, segment_numbers, length_bytes);

            free(buffer);
        }
    }

    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

nrsc5's packets are similar to AAC BUT are: `2048 samples, but each packet affects 4096 samples`. [Quote here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59332275/8075127)